# Received an invalid column length from the bcp client for colid 6

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I want to bulk upload csv file data to sql server 2005 from c# code but I am encountering the below error -

> Received an invalid column length from the bcp client for colid 6.

when bulk copy write to database server

Answer (score 73, accepted):

One of the data columns in the excel (Column Id 6) has one or more cell data that exceed the datacolumn datatype length in the database.

Verify the data in excel. Also verify the data in the excel for its format to be in compliance with the database table schema.

To avoid this, try exceeding the data-length of the string datatype in the database table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Specifically, if you have any columns that are VARCHAR smaller than 4, watch out for NULL in your data getting misinterpreted as the 4char string "NULL"

Comment: @CrazyPyro My upvote. I was getting the same error due to what you mentioned in your comment above. I changed my column's data type from varchar(3) to varchar(5), and the error went away. The column does have NULL values. Thank you for sharing your thoughts.

Answer (score 243):

I know this post is old but I ran into this same issue and finally figured out a solution to determine which column was causing the problem and report it back as needed. I determined that **`colid`** returned in the SqlException is not zero based so you need to subtract 1 from it to get the value.  After that it is used as the index of the `_sortedColumnMappings` ArrayList of the SqlBulkCopy instance not the index of the column mappings that were added to the SqlBulkCopy instance.  One thing to note is that SqlBulkCopy will stop on the first error received so this may not be the only issue but at least helps to figure it out.

```
try
{
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(importTable);
    sqlTran.Commit();
}    
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Message.Contains("Received an invalid column length from the bcp client for colid"))
    {
        string pattern = @"\d+";
        Match match = Regex.Match(ex.Message.ToString(), pattern);
        var index = Convert.ToInt32(match.Value) -1;

        FieldInfo fi = typeof(SqlBulkCopy).GetField("_sortedColumnMappings", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var sortedColumns = fi.GetValue(bulkCopy);
        var items = (Object[])sortedColumns.GetType().GetField("_items", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(sortedColumns);

        FieldInfo itemdata = items[index].GetType().GetField("_metadata", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var metadata = itemdata.GetValue(items[index]);

        var column = metadata.GetType().GetField("column", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(metadata);
        var length = metadata.GetType().GetField("length", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(metadata);
        throw new DataFormatException(String.Format("Column: {0} contains data with a length greater than: {1}", column, length));
    }

    throw;
}
```

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to also get the row nr?

Comment: Where are you getting DataFormatException from? Is this a local class to your project? Also your code eats all other sql exceptions...maybe do a rethrow?

Comment: DataFormatException is a custom exception so I could report back the issue as the invalid column length.  I haven't been able to figure out how to get the row number yet.

Comment: Great solution, only thing missing is in the catch sqlTran.RollBack();

Comment: May be glaringly obvious for most, but _"the colid that is returned in the SqlException is not zero based"_ helped me snuff this out.

Comment: You can get the row number by checking the dataReader.Depth before it is disposed. If you're using a DataTable, I'm not sure how this may be done.

Comment: I am getting an error in objbulk in the Catch statement. 'Use of unassigned local variable objbulk'

Comment: It's a pity that Microsoft did not expose the metadata as public get-only properties.

Comment: Great piece of code, but keep in mind that the error message will depend on Windows language.

Comment: I would love to make use of this code, but I'm getting this error on an ADO.net destination task. This error is driving me nuts!

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this!  It helped me solve my issue!

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar kind of issue while passing a string to Database table using  SQL BulkCopy option. The string i was passing was of 3 characters whereas the destination column length was `varchar(20)`. I tried trimming the string before inserting into DB using `Trim()` function to check if the issue was due to any space (leading and trailing) in the string. After trimming the string, it worked fine.

You can try `text.Trim()`

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot! That was the exact reason in my case as well - trailing whitespace and as a result column length exceeded.

Comment: If the string might be null, use text?.Trim()

Answer (score 2):

Check the size of the columns in the table you are doing bulk insert/copy. the varchar or other string columns might needs to be extended or the value your are inserting needs to be trim. Column order also should be same as in table.

e.g, Increase size of varchar column 30 to 50 =>

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName]
ALTER COLUMN [ColumnName] Varchar(50)

Answer (score 2):

I have been using SqlBulkCopy to transfer an Access database to SQL. Simply put, I create each table in SQL, load the corresponding Access table into a DataTable, then SqlBulkCopy the DataTable to the corresponding SQL table. Because I used a standardized function to do this, I did not setup any ColumnMappings.  When there are no ColumnMappings, SqlBulkCopy seems to simply map column 0 to column 0, column 1 to column 1, etc.

In my case, I had to make sure that the column order in my Access table matched the column order in my new SQL table EXACTLY. Once I did that, it ran as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Great piece of code, thanks for sharing!

I ended up using reflection to get the actual DataMemberName to throw back to a client on an error (I'm using bulk save in a WCF service).  Hopefully someone else will find how I did it useful.

```js
static string GetDataMemberName(string colName, object t) {
  foreach(PropertyInfo propertyInfo in t.GetType().GetProperties()) {
    if (propertyInfo.CanRead) {
      if (propertyInfo.Name == colName) {
        var attributes = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataMemberAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() as DataMemberAttribute;
        if (attributes != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(attributes.Name))
          return attributes.Name;
        return colName;
      }
    }
  }
  return colName;
}
```

Comment: How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message with a much more recent ssis version (vs 2015 enterprise, i think it's ssis 2016).  I will comment here because this is the first reference that comes up when you google this error message.  I think it happens mostly with character columns when the source character size is larger than the target character size.   I got this message when I was using an ado.net input to ms sql from a teradata database.   Funny because the prior oledb writes to ms sql handled all the character conversion perfectly with no coding overrides.  The colid number and the a corresponding Destination Input column # you sometimes get with the colid message are worthless.  It's not the column when you count down from the top of the mapping or anything like that. If I were microsoft, I'd be embarrased to give an error message that looks like it's pointing at the problem column when it isn't.  I found the problem colid by making an educated guess and then changing the input to the mapping to "Ignore" and then rerun and see if the message went away.  In my case and in my environment I fixed it by substr( 'ing the Teradata input to the character size of the ms sql declaration for the output column.   Check and make sure your input substr propagates through all you data conversions and mappings.   In my case it didn't and I had to delete all my Data Conversion's and Mappings and start over again. Again funny that OLEDB just handled it and ADO.net threw the error and had to have all this intervention to make it work.  In general you should use OLEDB when your target is MS Sql.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this and using @b_stil's snippet, I was able to figure the culprit column. And on futher investigation, I figured i needed to trim the column just like @Liji Chandran suggested but I was using IExcelDataReader and I couldn't figure out an easy way to validate and trim each of my 160 columns.

Then I stumbled upon [this class, (ValidatingDataReader)](https://www.csvreader.com/posts/ValidatingDataReader.cs) class from [CSVReader](https://www.csvreader.com/posts/validating_datareader.php).

Interesting thing about this class is that it gives you the source and destination columns data length, the culprit row and even the column value that's causing the error.

All I did was just trim all (nvarchar, varchar, char and nchar) columns.

I just changed my `GetValue` method to this:

```
 object IDataRecord.GetValue(int i)
    {
        object columnValue = reader.GetValue(i);

        if (i > -1 && i < lookup.Length)
        {
            DataRow columnDef = lookup[i];
            if
            (
                (
                    (string)columnDef["DataTypeName"] == "varchar" ||
                    (string)columnDef["DataTypeName"] == "nvarchar" ||
                    (string)columnDef["DataTypeName"] == "char" ||
                    (string)columnDef["DataTypeName"] == "nchar"
                ) &&
                (
                    columnValue != null &&
                    columnValue != DBNull.Value
                )
            )
            {
                string stringValue = columnValue.ToString().Trim();

                columnValue = stringValue;


                if (stringValue.Length > (int)columnDef["ColumnSize"])
                {
                    string message =
                        "Column value \"" + stringValue.Replace("\"", "\\\"") + "\"" +
                        " with length " + stringValue.Length.ToString("###,##0") +
                        " from source column " + (this as IDataRecord).GetName(i) +
                        " in record " + currentRecord.ToString("###,##0") +
                        " does not fit in destination column " + columnDef["ColumnName"] +
                        " with length " + ((int)columnDef["ColumnSize"]).ToString("###,##0") +
                        " in table " + tableName +
                        " in database " + databaseName +
                        " on server " + serverName + ".";

                    if (ColumnException == null)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(message);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ColumnExceptionEventArgs args = new ColumnExceptionEventArgs();

                        args.DataTypeName = (string)columnDef["DataTypeName"];
                        args.DataType = Type.GetType((string)columnDef["DataType"]);
                        args.Value = columnValue;
                        args.SourceIndex = i;
                        args.SourceColumn = reader.GetName(i);
                        args.DestIndex = (int)columnDef["ColumnOrdinal"];
                        args.DestColumn = (string)columnDef["ColumnName"];
                        args.ColumnSize = (int)columnDef["ColumnSize"];
                        args.RecordIndex = currentRecord;
                        args.TableName = tableName;
                        args.DatabaseName = databaseName;
                        args.ServerName = serverName;
                        args.Message = message;

                        ColumnException(args);

                        columnValue = args.Value;
                    }
                }



            }
        }

        return columnValue;
    }
```

Hope this helps someone