# C# removing unicode character

Tags: c#, excel, unicode, sqlbulkcopy

I'm attempting to insert text data from an Excel worksheet in to a MS SQL table using the C# sqlBulkCopy class. The problem I'm having is I get the notorious *Received an invalid column length from the bcp client for colid 6* error. I later find out that the real problem is Excel Unicode formatting within the notes texts.  if I just enter notes into the Excel cells the data insert works, otherwise it fails. Here is the code I'm attempting use in my C# script:

```
 SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(DBconn.ConnectionString);
            {
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "##MasterFileTemp";



                foreach (DataColumn dc in MasterFileTemp.Columns)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j < MasterFileTemp.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (MasterFileTemp.Rows[0][dc].ToString() == "Notes")
                        {

                            int pos = dc.Ordinal;
                            string dataText = Regex.Replace(MasterFileTemp.Rows[j][pos].ToString(), @"[^\u0000-\u007F]", string.Empty);
                            MasterFileTemp.Rows[j][pos] = dataText;
                            MasterFileTemp.AcceptChanges();
                            MessageBox.Show(MasterFileTemp.Rows[j][pos].ToString());


                        }
                    }
                }
                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(MasterFileTemp);
```

This is what the Excel text data looks like, notice the leading and trailing double quotes generated by Excel:

" -If additional information is needed, contact the partner requester on the Service Order Tab within the work space.  For any other operational issues, email James

**Service requests include Portfolio Management (Watch list), Foreclosure, Pre-Foreclosure, Other Real Estate Owned (OREO), Asset Valuation only (no loan)

"

```
string strCn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;\";";
string GetExcelData = "Select * From [" + tabName + "A23:Z100]";
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(strCn);
OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(GetExcelData, cn);
                    DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
                    objAdapter2.Fill(ds2, "dSheet1");
                    DataTable dt2 = ds2.Tables["dSheet1"];


      Here the entired code:
```

namespace ST_426cda87cffe4ef6a10722ecf5f7fe65.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

```
    #region VSTA generated code
    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion

    public void Main()
    {

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Dts.Variables["User::MasterFileTemplate"].Value.ToString(),
             0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);

        String[] excelSheets = new String[excelBook.Worksheets.Count];
        int z = 0;
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet wSheet in excelBook.Worksheets)
        {
            excelSheets[z] = wSheet.Name;
            z++;
        }
        excelBook.Close(false, Dts.Variables["User::MasterFileTemplate"].Value.ToString(), Missing.Value);
        xlApp.Quit();
        process_worksheets(excelSheets);
    }

    public void process_worksheets(string[] wsheets)
       {
        int r;            
        string[] vars = new string[1];
        string field;
        string filePath = (Dts.Variables["User::MasterFileTemplate"].Value.ToString());
        string DataServer = (Dts.Variables["User::DataServer"].Value.ToString());
        string strCn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;\";";


          for (r=0; r < wsheets.Length; r++)
               {
                string tabName = wsheets[r].ToString() + "$";
                string GetExcelDate = "Select * From [" + tabName + "A15:B16]";   //This is the Excel line number for Prod Completed date and Completed by
                string GetExcelData = "Select * From [" + tabName + "A23:Z100]";  //This is the Excel line number where the header columns and data start   

                OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(strCn);
                SqlConnection DBconn = new SqlConnection();
                DBconn.ConnectionString = "Data Source="+DataServer + ";Initial Catalog=FNC;" + "Integrated Security=SSPI";

                OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(GetExcelDate, cn);

                // This Dataset contains the header columns and data
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                objAdapter.Fill(ds, "dSheet1");
                DataTable dt = ds.Tables["dSheet1"];

                ///****  Parse Excel Serial Date  ***/
                string dtt = (dt.Rows[0][1].ToString());
                DateTime signoffDte = DateTime.Parse(dtt);
                DateTime currentDte = System.DateTime.Today;

                /// Check to see if Production sign-off date is less than current date and signed by is empty
                if ((signoffDte > currentDte) || (dt.Rows[1][1].ToString() == ""))
                {
                 //   MessageBox.Show(tabName.ToString() + "Date requirment Failed..processing next");
                    continue;  //Skip worksheet if Production signoff date or signature is invalid
                }
                else
                {
                    //This Dataset contains the header columns and data
                    OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(GetExcelData, cn);
                    DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
                    objAdapter2.Fill(ds2, "dSheet1");
                    DataTable dt2 = ds2.Tables["dSheet1"];


                    DataTable dth = dt2.Clone();
                    dth.ImportRow(dt2.Rows[0]);

                    /*** Create Master File Temp Table from Excel Template source file ***/
                    CreateTempTableAndBulkCopyData(dt2,DBconn);

                    /*****************************************************************************/
                    /*   Loop thru Excel Template File and only select the first row (Headers)   */
                    /*****************************************************************************/

                    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)  //Gets first row "A1:Z1" (column headers of excel spreadsheet)
                    {
                        // y=3 is static and must not be changed. This sets Partner_org_PK,Partner_ID,Partner_Name as key columns to perform SQL JOIN on
                        for (int y = 3; y < dth.Columns.Count; y++)
                        {
                            field = dth.Rows[0][y].ToString();
                            vars[0] = field;
                           UpdateMasterFileTable(DBconn, vars, dth); // Performs an update to the Partner Profile Table via a join on the Master File Temp table 

                        }
                        UpdateValidation(DBconn, dth, tabName);
                    }
                    ds.Clear();
                    ds2.Clear();
                    dt.Clear();
                    dth.Clear();

                    cn.Close();
                    DBconn.Close();
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Processed......" + tabName.ToString());
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
 }
     /**************************************************************************************************/
     /*   Creates Master File Global Temp Table ###MasterFileTemp and Bulk Copy Excel data into it   */
     /**************************************************************************************************/
    public static void CreateTempTableAndBulkCopyData(DataTable dt2, SqlConnection DBconn)
    {
        DataTable MasterFileTemp = dt2;



        string createTempTable = "CREATE TABLE ##MasterFileTemp(";
        foreach (DataColumn dc in MasterFileTemp.Columns)
        {
            createTempTable += MasterFileTemp.Rows[0][dc] + " Varchar(255),";
        }
        createTempTable = createTempTable.Remove(createTempTable.Length - 1);   //remove trailing, unecessary comma
        createTempTable += ")"; // cap-off with ")" to complete the CREATE ##TEMP TABLE DDL
        {

            //Create temp table command
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(createTempTable, DBconn);
            DBconn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show(createTempTable.ToString());

            //Copy the DataTable to SQL Server Table using SqlBulkCopy
            SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(DBconn.ConnectionString);
            {
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "##MasterFileTemp";

                foreach (DataColumn dc in MasterFileTemp.Columns)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j < MasterFileTemp.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (MasterFileTemp.Rows[0][dc].ToString() == "Notes")
                        {

                            int pos = dc.Ordinal;
                            string dataText = MasterFileTemp.Rows[j][pos].ToString().Replace("\r\n", String.Empty);
                            MasterFileTemp.Rows[j][pos] = dataText;
                            MasterFileTemp.AcceptChanges();
                            //MessageBox.Show(MasterFileTemp.Rows[j][pos].ToString());

                        }
                    }
                }
                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(MasterFileTemp);

            }
        }
    }
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    /*   Performs an up to the Partner Profile Table via a UPDATE join on the Master File Temp table  */
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    public void UpdateMasterFileTable(SqlConnection DBconn, string[] vars, DataTable dth)
        {
         string[] upvariable = vars;
         string sqlUpate = "UPDATE [dbo].[xstg_Partner_Profile]" +
         " SET [dbo].[xstg_Partner_Profile]." + upvariable[0] + "=##MasterFileTemp." + upvariable[0] +
         " FROM ##MasterFileTemp" +
         " WHERE [dbo].[xstg_Partner_Profile].Partner_Id= ##MasterFileTemp." + dth.Rows[0][1].ToString() +
         " AND [dbo].[xstg_Partner_Profile].Partner_Name= ##MasterFileTemp." + dth.Rows[0][2].ToString();
          SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlUpate, DBconn);
           command.ExecuteNonQuery();
          MessageBox.Show(sqlUpate.ToString());

         }
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    /*   Performs the update validation against production 90100 UI Report and creates Excel mismatch */
    /*   output for each worksheet tab in masterfileupdate template
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    public void UpdateValidation(SqlConnection DBconn, DataTable dth, string tabName)
    {
        string SelectSQL;
        string SelectFields=null;
        for (int x = 3; x < dth.Columns.Count; x++)
        {
           SelectFields += " p2." +dth.Rows[0][x]+ ", ";
        }
        SelectFields = SelectFields.Remove(SelectFields.Length - 2);  //remove trailing comma
        SelectSQL = "SELECT p2.Partner_ID, p2.Partner_Name,";
        SelectSQL += SelectFields;
        string ValidationSQL = " FROM (select * from dbo.Partner_Profile_CMS_Settings) p1" +
                               " FULL OUTER JOIN (Select * from dbo.xstg_Partner_Profile) p2" +
                               " ON p1.Partner_ID = p2.Partner_ID and p1.Partner_Name=p2.Partner_Name" +
                               " WHERE";

        SelectSQL += ValidationSQL; //Append select statement as one
        string ValidationSQLWhere=null;
        for (int y = 3; y < dth.Columns.Count; y++) //loop through data columns to get columns for update - mismatch. This is dynamic and makes up the Where clause
        {
            ValidationSQLWhere += " (P1."+dth.Rows[0][y]+" <> p2."+dth.Rows[0][y]+") OR";
        }
        ValidationSQLWhere = ValidationSQLWhere.Remove(ValidationSQLWhere.Length - 2);  //Remove "OR" two characters from the select statement where clause
        SelectSQL += ValidationSQLWhere; //Append Where clause string to main Select string
        MessageBox.Show("Validating... " + tabName); //Display entire string

        //Build SQL connection to run mismatch query, passing in SELECT statement above
        SqlDataAdapter VSAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectSQL, DBconn);
        // This Dataset contains Vaildate data
        DataSet validateDs = new DataSet();
        VSAdapter.Fill(validateDs, "VSheet1");
        DataTable validationTemp = validateDs.Tables["VSheet1"];
        String currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy");
        String outputStatus="Validation is 100% accurate";


        /* Set up Excel workbook instance and loop through each worksheet avaialble file output */
        /****************************************************************************************/
        Excel.Application oXL = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;
        Excel.Workbooks oWBs = oXL.Workbooks;
        Excel.Workbook oWB = null;
        Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
        tabName = tabName.Remove(tabName.Length-1);  //remove training '$' from mismatch worksheets

        /* If the mismatch output file does not exist, create mismatch file and write out first worksheet */
        if (!File.Exists(Dts.Variables["User::MismatchOutputFile"].Value.ToString()))
        {


            oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
            // Get the active sheet 
            oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            oSheet.Name = tabName;

            int rowCount = 0;
            if (validationTemp.Rows.Count >= 1)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in validationTemp.Rows)
                {
                    rowCount += 1;
                    for (int i = 1; i < validationTemp.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                    {
                        // Add the header time first only
                        if (rowCount == 2)
                        {
                            oSheet.Cells[1, i] = validationTemp.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
                        }                           
                        oSheet.Cells[rowCount, i] = dr[i - 1].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
               // MessageBox.Show("Validation is 100% accurate");
                oSheet.Cells[rowCount, 2] = outputStatus.ToString();
            }
            oWB.SaveAs(Dts.Variables["User::MismatchOutputFile"].Value.ToString(), Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
               Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
               Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared,
               Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
               Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
         }
        else /* If mismatch file already exists, loop thru and append additional worksheets */
        {
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            try
            {
                oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;
                Excel.Sheets xlSheets = null;
                oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(Dts.Variables["User::MismatchOutputFile"].Value.ToString(),
                         Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                         Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                         Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                         Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
                xlSheets = (Excel.Sheets)oWB.Sheets;
                oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlSheets.Add(Type.Missing, xlSheets[1], Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                oSheet.Name = tabName;
                int rowCount = 0;
                if (validationTemp.Rows.Count > 1)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow dr in validationTemp.Rows)
                    {
                        rowCount += 1;
                        for (int i = 1; i < validationTemp.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                        {
                            // Add the header time first only
                            if (rowCount == 2)
                            {
                                oSheet.Cells[1, i] = validationTemp.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
                            }
                            oSheet.Cells[rowCount, i] = dr[i - 1].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                 }else
                        {
                           // MessageBox.Show("Validation is 100% accurate");
                            oSheet.Cells[rowCount, 2] = outputStatus.ToString();
                        }   
                oWB.SaveAs(Dts.Variables["User::MismatchOutputFile"].Value.ToString(), Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
                   Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                   Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
                   Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                   Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
                oWB.Close(true, Dts.Variables["User::MismatchOutputFile"].Value.ToString(), Type.Missing);
                oWBs.Close();
                oXL.Quit();
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oXL);
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }

    }
```

}

}

---

Comment: If you try to insert a value that is larger than the table column's length, you'll get an error. There's nothing notorious about this. Either enlarge the column or check your data. .NET users Unicode throughout, so trying to found Unicode errors is meaningless. Besides, Unicode isn't related to *formatting* at all. Is there a reason this shouldn't be closed as a duplicat of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442686/received-an-invalid-column-length-from-the-bcp-client-for-colid-6) ?

Comment: If there *is* a problem with the data, you should check the code that reads the Excel file. You haven't provided this though, so it's impossible to help. *How* are you reading the file? Using the Jet driver? EPPlus? Using Excel Interop? If you are reading it as text, you don't have an Excel file at all - Excel uses a binary file format

Comment: Excel doesn't generate quotes. As I said, it's a binary format. I suspect you are trying to load a CSV file that uses an `xls` or `xlsx` extension to fool Excel. Post the code you are using to read the CSV. Note though that storing text with newlines in a CSV file isn't the brightest idea - CSV is supposed to be a **simple**, not a precise format

Comment: Please post the code that reads the CSV. It's impossible to help otherwise. Whoever generates the files saved data with newlines in text columns. If you try to load the file line-by-line, you'll end up reading wrong data. The problem is the *newline* in the text, not Unicode

Comment: I'm reading in the Excel worksheet as *.xlsx.  The Data entry personnel is copying/pasting in the text notes from another source.  my script  imports the worksheet data into a C# datatable where I massage the data before bulk copying into the db table

Comment: Also, I modified the "notes" column to nvarchar(max) but  the error still remains.. thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are saying Excel, but your code is using a DataTable. Why wouldn't you directly SqlBulkCopy from the Excel itself?

Instead of using a global temp table, you could SqlBulkCopy to a local temp table, setting the text fields' datatype to NVarchar(max) and you shouldn't have a problem. SQL server supports unicode.

Edit: Ahha, I think now I see where you are going wrong. "Excel generated text data" you say. Is that a CSV file? Excel doesn't know how to save a legal CSV in the first place. Don't save to a text file. If you do, then there isn't an 'importer' that could read that data back right. Instead directly SqlBulkCopy from Excel without using any other intermediate text file or datatable.

Comment: What do you mean by local and global temp tables? A DataTable is an in-memory ADO.NET class. As for CSVs, the OP isn't trying to save Excel to a CSV, it seems he is trying to load a CSV that masquerades as an Excel file. Regarding "legal" CSVs, there is no strict specification of the CSV format. Excel can easily generate a CSV readable by any other program. The data posted by the OP though shows that whoever exported the CSV, included newlines in text columns. Most csv reading code will fail in this case as most programmers expect to read CSVs line-by-line

Comment: If you read his first line in code, it is saying ( sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "##MasterFileTemp"; ). It denotes a global temp table in MS SQL server, no? Instead of using a global one, he could have used a local one. It has nothing to do with a DataTable. And also as I said, if it is Excel then he doesn't need a DataTable in between nor does he need to use an intermediate CSV file. And also as I noted, Excel is incapable of writing legal CSV files (to Excel, anything with a header row + ...

Comment: cell contents written separated by comma is a CSV - but in fact CSV is more than simply being a CommaSeparatedValue and there should be different character(s) for  row terminator if CR\LF is used in data). Excel CANNOT generate such a legal CSV, it spits out CR\LF for text data and also as row terminator.

Comment: First, whether it's a temporary table or not doesn't matter for this question. Second, the OP isn't using a CSV after all, he is using the Jet driver to read the data from the Excel file. Finally, there's nothing wrong with using `\r\n` as a line separator. It doesn't mean the file is "illegal" - there is no official CSV standard. As for the DataTable, a DataTable, DataReader or array of DataRows *is* needed by SqlBulkCopy

Comment: I didn't say it was directly related, but if it were a local temp table then he would have more control over it. It was a suggestion, not a "must" item. When I first read it, it wasn't saying that it isn't a CSV, part he sent looked like a CSV - he were saying "generated" and sample with double quotes that make me think a CSV was in question. If you use \r\n both within a field and also as a row terminator, then it is an illegal CSV - or a CSV beyond normal parsers if you will. A DataReader is just fine, he doesn't need the DataTable which may be the culprit in between.

Comment: Gentlemen, I any idea of the root cause for my problem? Thanks Ryan

Comment: Did you try not using that DataTable in between and directly with the DataReader? We really didn't see your create table and ColumnMappings code. I assume no chance that you could upload a sample xlsx somewhere for us to test.

Comment: full ssis script is  posted..  i have not attempted to use the dataReader class as alternative to sqlbulkcopy

Comment: I didn't mean to use DataReader instead of SqlBulkCopy class. I said to use DataReader in place of DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.  I identified that the column sizes where too small to accomodate the sqlBlkCopy operation.  Change the size from varchar(255) to varchar(2000)