# Get the line number on which the request to database ended with an error

Tags: c#, sql-server, reflection, sqlbulkcopy

I use this code to send a SQL request:

```
 SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(Connection);

 foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
 {
     bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName);
 }

 bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "nsi." + classifierData.Info.TableName;
 bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
```

and get this exception :

> Received an invalid column length from the bcp client for colid

Is there any way to identify which row is causing the error?

I've tried to use this, but it doesn't work (values are always the same):

```
 FieldInfo currentRow = typeof(SqlBulkCopy).GetField("_currentRowLength", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance);
 var currentRowNumber = currentRow.GetValue(bulkCopy);

 FieldInfo _rowsCopiedField = typeof(SqlBulkCopy).GetField("_rowsCopied", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance);
 var currentRowN = _rowsCopiedField.GetValue(bulkCopy);
```

Please, help me anyone ...

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/19712572/2832222

Comment: now, in this question  find a column number...

Comment: @b_stil provides a way to find the data causing the error ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/19712572/2832222

Comment: only by column, not by row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only way to identify the row in error from purely `SqlBulkCopy` is using the [NotifyAfter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.notifyafter) property + [SqlRowsCopied](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.sqlrowscopied) event + BatchSize = 1.

From these, you can now easily have an `Index` property that you increment for every successfully copied row and you will be able to find the index in error.

For example, an error is thrown and you re-try with `NotifyAfter = 1`

```
bulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied += new SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler(OnSqlRowsCopied);
bulkCopy.NotifyAfter = 1;
bulkCopy.BatchSize = 1;
```

Obviously, not the best performance wise solution but you will find your information.

**EDIT**: Answer comment

> Sorry, but can I get a value of row-column with error?

I don't think so. We don't know exactly which column have an issue with the error message.

Comment: Thank for the answer. But it always set a one value for any request.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of your last comment.

Comment: Sorry, I forget that you also need to set the batch size to 1. As said, that will not be as fast as normal but at least you will find the row in error.

Comment: Sorry, but can I get a value of row-column with error?