# SqlBulkCopy got exception : "Received an invalid column length from the bcp client for colid ."

Tags: c#, sql-server, bcp

I have code using `SqlBulkCopy` to clone a lot of tables, it used to work before, but very weird, recently got exception

> Received an invalid column length from the bcp client for colid

I have search this exception and still not solve my problem.

`sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader)` will raise this exception if a table has two continous columns which are both of type `Char(1)` or `nvarchar(nn)`, and both have `NULL`. Sometime, changing the `SqlBulkCopy.BatchSize` makes it work, but many times, it will not.

After simplify, I have test case as follow, and it is reproduceable on two servers:

1. Create a table like below: (tested on SQL Server 2012 SP 4 and SQL Server 2016 SP2)

   ```
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TestTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE dbo.TestTable;

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]
    (
        [value2] [char](1) NULL,
        [value1] [char](1) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO


    DECLARE @i int = 0

    WHILE @i < 262
    BEGIN
        SET @i = @i + 1

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable]([value2], [value1]) 
        VALUES (null, null)
    END
   ```
2. C# console (.net framework 4.7) code as below

   ```
    class Program
    {
        // [change here] 
        static string sourceConn = @"Server={YourServer};Database={YourDatabase};User ID={userYourName};Password={yourPassword};connect timeout=15";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CopyTable(sourceConn, sourceConn, "TestTable", "testTableBAK");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void CopyTable(string sConnSource, string sConnDest, string sTableSource, string sTableDest)
        {
            if (IsTableExist(sConnDest, sTableDest))
            {
                RunNonQuerySQL(sConnDest, "DROP TABLE " + sTableDest);
                Console.WriteLine($"existing table  {sTableDest} dropped");
            }

            CopySchema(sConnDest, sTableSource, sTableDest);

            using (SqlConnection connSource = new SqlConnection(sConnSource))
            {
                connSource.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = connSource;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + sTableSource;

                // using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sConnDest, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls | SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sConnDest))
                {
                    // sqlBulkCopy.BatchSize = 1380; // this optional setting will work if set value smaller than 1397 for testTable on my new server (SQL server  13.0.5102.14)
                    // sqlBulkCopy.BatchSize = 261; // this optional setting will work if set value smaller than 261 for testTable on 2 older server (SQL server  11.0.7001)
                    sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = sTableDest;
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    try
                    {
                        // exception here 
                        sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);  
                        Console.WriteLine("table copied");
                    }
                    catch (SqlException ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }

                    sqlBulkCopy.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        static bool IsTableExist(string sConn, string sTableName)
        {
            bool result = false;

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sConn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                string[] s = sTableName.Split('.');

                if (s.Length > 1)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "select count (*) as counter from information_schema.tables where table_name = '" + s[1] + "' and TABLE_SCHEMA='" + s[0] + "'";
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "select count (*) as counter from information_schema.tables  where table_name = '" + sTableName + "'";
                }
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                var count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                result = count > 0;
            }

            return result;
        }

        static bool RunNonQuerySQL(string sConn, string sSQL)
        {
            bool result = false;

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sConn))
            {
                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = sSQL;
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                var count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                result = true;
            }

            return result;
        }

        static public bool CopySchema(string sConn, string sTableSource, string sTableDest)
        {
            return RunQuerySQL(sConn, "select * into " + sTableDest + " from " + sTableSource + " where 1=2");
        }

        static public bool RunQuerySQL(string sConn, string sSQL)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sConn))
            {
                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = sSQL;
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: erm, RunNonQuerySQL() always returns true or could throw. that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: If you have any columns that are VARCHAR smaller than 4, watch out for NULL in your data getting misinterpreted as the 4char string "NULL"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442686/received-an-invalid-column-length-from-the-bcp-client-for-colid-6

Comment: Aside: you should be disposing your commands and readers with `using`

Comment: Hi, Mitch, I had read the link you give above, but it is different from my case, it is import from csv file and data length is longer than column defined.

Comment: @Charlieface, thanks for point, yes, I should add using

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this error.

I tried to insert a string with a lenght of 5 into a table column with a definition of "varchar(4)".

The error message in my case was:
*"Received an invalid column length from the bcp client for colid 2".*

"Colid 2" refered to the second column of the row (`DataRow`) that was part of the `DataTable` which I used as parameter for the call to the `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable table)` method.

The solution in my case was to add validation code that checks the lenght of the strings in my input data before trying to call `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer()`.